# Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0 in iOS

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am trying to Hide and show the table view cells in each section by clicking a button. I have read all the related issue about this but i can't see any relevant answer to my problem. There is no problem in hiding them one by one (meaning not both), but when the other section in a cell is hidden (removed/no cell), then i click the button. i am having this error:

Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-2935.137/UITableView.m:1368
2014-06-18 13:20:26.560 Head2Head[2001:60b] Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (2) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (0), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).

And here is my code:

```
-(void) commentButtonClicked:(id) sender{
UIButton *btn = (UIButton *) sender;
indexClicked = btn.tag -1;

if (!commentClicked) {
    commentClicked = YES;
}else{
    commentClicked = NO;
}

@try {
    [tableView1 beginUpdates];
    [tableView1 reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:btn.tag-1] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    [tableView1 endUpdates];

}
@catch (NSException *exception) {
    NSLog(@"%@", exception);
}
@finally {

}
```

}

And....

```
-(NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
NSString *numberOfRows = [commentsArray objectAtIndex:section];

if (commentClicked && indexClicked == section) {
    return 0;
}else{
    return [numberOfRows integerValue];
}
```

}

Comment: Did you try to debug and log the values of `commentClicked`, `indexClicked` and `[numberOfRows integerValue]` second time?

Comment: Small code suggestion: Replace your first `if` statement with `commentClicked = !commentClicked;`

Comment: Himashu Joshi i have log commentClicked and indexClicked. when i click on the button (remove the tableview cell) the value of commentClick is 1 and the value of indexClicked is 0. when i click the button again (showing the cell) in the first section of uitableview, both became 0. The value of [numberofRows intValue] is 5,2,5,2. i put the log on -(NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section

Comment: Marc Mosby- Code doesn't work. But thank you for the answer

Comment: I am returning 0 for the number of rows if the button is clicked for hiding, and return the number of arrays if the button is clicked for showing. in -(NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{} Function.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to reload both sections. The one that is already hidden and the one you are going to hide.

Comment: i tried reloading the both sections. and hav another error. the two sections are both hiding and show when the button is clicked.

Comment: That exception is still coming or its gone?

Comment: Are u storing the previously hidden section index and reloading that section? Can u plz post ur updated code?

Comment: Are you having separate comment button for each section? And can multiple sections at a time be hidden? If that is the case you need to maintain separate commentClicked status for each section.

Comment: is there anyway of implementing this?.

Comment: then how do u decide for which section the comment button is pressed?

Comment: On what basis r u setting the tag to button?

Comment: yes on button pressed. I'm setting the tag base on the no. of clicks. then i subtract and add something like that to cycle.

Comment: No of clicks means? Can u plz tell what u want do?

Comment: OK for this there is separate comment button for each section right?

Comment: i have used a single button now. but didn't fix the issue yet

Comment: I am not still clear about how u r hiding the individual sections using single button. The prototype that u posted yesterday was having separate comment button for each section.

Comment: yes i am using separate button now. but i can't still fix it. can you give me a sample code or site perhaps?.

Comment: If u have ur sample project pass that here. So that pepl will try to fix the issue.

Comment: https://github.com/OliverLetterer/SLExpandableTableView.  If u want can take a look at this.

Comment: the project on the link is incomplete. there is no SLExpandableTableView

Comment: i downloaded the zip and can't run it.

Comment: SLExpandableTableView.h file not found with <angled> include;

Comment: diff: /../Podfile.lock: No such file or directory
diff: /Manifest.lock: No such file or directory
error: The sandbox is not in sync with the Podfile.lock. Run 'pod install' or update your CocoaPods installation.

Comment: Diff: /../Podfile.lock: No such file or directory
Diff: /Manifest . lock: No such file or directory
The sandbox is not in sync with the Podfile.lock. Run 'pod install' or update your CocoaPods installation.

Comment: If u r facing the problem with cocoa pods just delete the cocoa pod from ur proj and run it.

Comment: yes. i deleted it. more errors now. alright. i think i have to fix it my self.

Comment: ok. Delete pod proj files from ur proj,libPod from link library build phases,delete runs scripts related to cocoaPod, and add the .h and .m files of expandable tableview into your project.